# Accessing VueJS "this" within my leaflet extension

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

I'm working with Leaflet within my Vuejs app and have created an extension of L.Control that could benefit tremendously if I could manage bits of it with Vuex. I'm just not entirely sure how to properly get the `this` of my Vue app inside of the `L.Control.extend` method.

Right now, I'm defining `let that = this;` and utilizing `that` anytime I want to deal with Vuejs data, but is this the best way? Does this have limitations?

Here's a stripped-down example of how I am currently implementing this.

```
mounted() {

    let that = this;

    L.Control.ZoomUserLocation = L.Control.extend({

    _zoomUserLocation: function() {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function success(position) {
              let lat = position.coords.latitude;
              let lng = position.coords.longitude;

              if (that.userLocationMarker !== null) {
                that.userLocationMarker.remove();
              }
              that.userLocationMarker = L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(map);
            },
            function error(error_message) {...}
          );
        } 
        else {
          map.setView([that.center.lat, that.center.lng], that.zoom);
        }
      },
    })
}
```

Comment: I do this also (only when necessary though), because it's quick and easy. I've never ran into problems with it. What kinds of limitations are you thinking this way has?

Comment: `let that = this` is the common solution before `ES6`. You can also use the arrow function to get this in the `ES6`, `_zoomUserLocation: () => { console.log(this) }`

Comment: Does this not impact the reactivity that comes with vue?